# What difference total_count and index_count in _stats of elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm Cha :)

I was created index in Elasticsearch ( Name is indexAAA ) and i wrote a documents about 5000.
and I execute a url like below.
GET http://IP:PORT/indexAAA/_stats

Then i saw a two fields (total_count, index_count).

count: 5000
index_total: 4101

Q1. What's meaning of index_total?

Q2. Why difference count and index_total value?

Q3. As i know I can set options about index, how can i judge my index good or bad?

Q4. For example if another index has count:5000, index_total:5000 , is this good index? or bad index?

Best regards
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no `index_count` field returned by the `_stats` endpoint.

The `*.query_cache.total_count` stats field contains the number of elements cached in the [node query cache](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-cache.html).

The `*.docs.count` is the total number of documents present in the index.

The `*.indexing.index_total` stats field contains the total number of indexing operation that have been carried out.

The last two figures can be different because the former will always be the total number of documents, while the latter is the number of indexing operations **since the last time the cluster restarted**. It's a counter that gets reset on every restart.

Comment: Is everything clear or do you need some more information?